# print command output stored in bash variabled as it with wothout removing new line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sh

i just want to write a bash program that stores top 5 process on variable as it is without removing new lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
getTopProcess(){
    top_output=$(top -n 1 -b -o %CPU | awk 'NR>=8 && NR <=12')
    echo $top_output
}

getTopProcess
```

but my code print all in same line, can anyone help me with this

output i get:

```
1937738 kavin-1+ 20 0 36.6g 153432 112596 S 6.2 1.0 0:22.70 code 1996549 root 20 0 23364 6208 4768 R 6.2 0.0 0:00.01 top 1 root 20 0 168216 10188 5496 S 0.0 0.1 1:28.14 systemd 2 root 20 0 0 0 0 S 0.0 0.0 0:00.62 kthreadd 3 root 0 -20 0 0 0 I 0.0 0.0 0:00.00 rcu_gp
```

output i want:

```
   1845 root      20   0 1407168   1372   1372 S   6.2   0.0   0:48.68 lwsmd
1851644 kavin-1+  20   0 1131.0g  88896  61588 S   6.2   0.6   0:48.23 ulaa
      1 root      20   0  168216  10188   5496 S   0.0   0.1   1:28.14 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.62 kthreadd
      3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp
```

Comment: Use quotes: `echo "$top_output"`. Better yet, use `printf` instead of `echo`: `printf '%s\n' "$top_output"`.

Comment: you need to double-quote the variable when you echo it.

Comment: `$top_output` undergoes word splitting. `echo` therefore does not see any new lines (nor does it see any space character BTW; that's why your `20    0` ends up displayed as `20 0`.

Comment: If you had run your code through http://shellcheck.net as the [tag:bash] tag you used tells you to do ("For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.") it would have told you about the error in your code and the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to double-quote the variable when you echo it, because by adding the double quotes around `"$top_output"`, the variable will be expanded with the newlines intact!

```
#!/bin/bash
getTopProcess(){
    top_output=$(top -n 1 -b -o %CPU | awk 'NR>=8 && NR <=12')
    echo "$top_output"
}

getTopProcess
```

output

```
  99476 root      20   0   16448  10084   8236 S  12.5   0.5   0:00.05 sshd
    559 root      20   0   80056   1512   1316 S   6.2   0.1  12:01.06 qemu-ga
    636 mysql     20   0 1361792 417352  19292 S   6.2  21.3 101:01.98 mysqld
  99480 root      20   0   10344   4088   3488 R   6.2   0.2   0:00.02 top
      1 root      20   0  167600  13096   8416 S   0.0   0.7   2:35.51 systemd
```

You can also use the `readarray` command, because it is used to read the output of the `top` command into the `top_output` array.

```
#!/bin/bash
getTopProcess(){
    readarray -t top_output < <(top -n 1 -b -o %CPU | awk 'NR>=8 && NR <=12')
    for line in "${top_output[@]}"; do
        echo "$line"
    done
}

getTopProcess
```